# Delete entry from related tables

Tags: mysql, relational-theory, delete

> I can not use InnoDB engine because of some dependency troubles in LuaSQL and PtokaX.

My current query is something like:

```
DELETE e.*, m.* 
FROM entries e 
INNER JOIN magnets m 
    ON m.eid = e.id
WHERE e.id = %d
```

where, `%d` is an integer passed by the user. This query works if there is atleast one entry in the `magnets` table related to the `entries` table.

But, it fails when the `entries` has no dependent row in `magnets` table. Can I modify this query to perform deletion from both tables, independent of child-rows in `magnets`? Or do I need to first check if a child exists and delete accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things you could try:

**`DELETE` Style #1 : `LEFT JOIN`**

```
DELETE e.*, m.* 
FROM `entries` e 
LEFT JOIN `magnets` m 
    ON m.`eid` = e.`id` 
WHERE e.`id` = %d
```

**`DELETE` Style #2 : Two Independent `DELETE` queries

(without `FOREIGN KEY` defined)**

```
DELETE FROM entries WHERE id = %d;
DELETE FROM magnets WHERE eid = %d;
```

**`DELETE` Style #2b : Two `DELETE` queries : the order matters

 (when there is a `FOREIGN KEY` defined between the two tables

 with the `ON DELETE NO ACTION` property)**

```
DELETE FROM magnets WHERE eid = %d;
DELETE FROM entries WHERE id = %d;
```

**`DELETE` Style #3 : One `DELETE` query

 (when there is a `FOREIGN KEY` defined

 with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` property)**

```
DELETE FROM entries WHERE id = %d;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

> DELETE CASCADE: When we create a foreign key using this option, it deletes the referencing rows in the child table when the referenced row is deleted in the parent table which has a primary key.

Actually you can make your life easier by setting the relationship that connects "magnets" and "entries" tables to CASCADE options.

In this way the deletion in the child table will be done automatically.